# Expanding items jump across two column layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap accordion on my site and have split it into a two column layout like so:

```css
#accordion {
  column-count: 2;
}

.card {
  margin: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
}
a{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading1">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">Heading1</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading1" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#">item1</a>
        <a href="#">item2</a>
        <a href="#">item3</a>
        <a href="#">item4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading2">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">Heading2</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading2" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#">item1</a>
        <a href="#">item2</a>
        <a href="#">item3</a>
        <a href="#">item4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading3">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse3">Heading3</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse3" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading3" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#">item1</a>
        <a href="#">item2</a>
        <a href="#">item3</a>
        <a href="#">item4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading4">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse4" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse4">Heading4</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse4" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading4" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#">item1</a>
        <a href="#">item2</a>
        <a href="#">item3</a>
        <a href="#">item4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading5">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse5" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse5">Heading5</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse5" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading5" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#">item1</a>
        <a href="#">item2</a>
        <a href="#">item3</a>
        <a href="#">item4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading6">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse6" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse6">Heading6</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse6" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading6" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#">item1</a>
        <a href="#">item2</a>
        <a href="#">item3</a>
        <a href="#">item4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading7">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse7" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse7">Heading7</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse7" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading7" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#">item1</a>
        <a href="#">item2</a>
        <a href="#">item3</a>
        <a href="#">item4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading8">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse8" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse8">Heading8</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse8" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading8" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#">item1</a>
        <a href="#">item2</a>
        <a href="#">item3</a>
        <a href="#">item4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading9">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse9" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse9">Heading9</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse9" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading9" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#">item1</a>
        <a href="#">item2</a>
        <a href="#">item3</a>
        <a href="#">item4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading10">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse10" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse10">Heading10</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse10" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading10" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#">item1</a>
        <a href="#">item2</a>
        <a href="#">item3</a>
        <a href="#">item4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However if you try to expand some of the lower items in the second column some of the ones at the top jump back to the column before it (this is more pronounced on my site with more items inside) which makes it hard for a user to select things properly.

The reason it is in two columns and not just split up in two inline divs is because it is generated by PHP and the number of accordions and items within them will change.

Is there any way to stop these jumping across columns when they have been expanded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed this by changing how it was generated in PHP instead of doing as suggested in one of the answers of adding them each to a new row I did this:

```
$i =0;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM headings";
$stmt = DB::run($sql);

$count = $stmt->rowCount();
$half_count = ceil($count/2);

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $i++;

    if($i==1 || $i==$half_count+1){
        $headings .= '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mt-5 mb-5">';
        $headings .= '<div id="accordion" class="index_accordion">';
    }

    // the rest of my original code

    if($i==$half_count || $i==$count){
        $headings .= '</div>';
        $headings .= '</div>';
    }
}
```

The issue now is that it now works as two seperate accordions and you can have items expanded on both sides.

Comment: this gives me two id's of 'accordion' which kind of messes things up a bit but if I put that div outside of my while loop then the columns aren't recognized and it just goes back to a one column layout

Answer (score 4):

Try using proper bootstrap function. Such as class="row" and column classes (I used "col-sm-6")...like this

```css
#accordion {
  column-count: 2;
}

.card {
  margin: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
}
a{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="accordion" class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
  
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="heading1">
        <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">Heading1</button>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading1" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="#">item1</a>
          <a href="#">item2</a>
          <a href="#">item3</a>
          <a href="#">item4</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="heading2">
        <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">Heading2</button>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading2" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="#">item1</a>
          <a href="#">item2</a>
          <a href="#">item3</a>
          <a href="#">item4</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="heading3">
        <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">Heading3</button>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading3" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="#">item1</a>
          <a href="#">item2</a>
          <a href="#">item3</a>
          <a href="#">item4</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="heading4">
        <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse4" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">Heading4</button>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse4" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading4" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="#">item1</a>
          <a href="#">item2</a>
          <a href="#">item3</a>
          <a href="#">item4</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="heading5">
        <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse5" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">Heading5</button>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse5" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading5" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="#">item1</a>
          <a href="#">item2</a>
          <a href="#">item3</a>
          <a href="#">item4</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="heading6">
        <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse6" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">Heading6</button>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse6" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading6" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="#">item1</a>
          <a href="#">item2</a>
          <a href="#">item3</a>
          <a href="#">item4</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="heading7">
        <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse7" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">Heading7</button>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse7" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading7" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="#">item1</a>
          <a href="#">item2</a>
          <a href="#">item3</a>
          <a href="#">item4</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="heading8">
        <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse8" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse8">Heading8</button>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse8" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading8" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="#">item1</a>
          <a href="#">item2</a>
          <a href="#">item3</a>
          <a href="#">item4</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="heading9">
        <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse9" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse9">Heading9</button>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse9" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading9" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="#">item1</a>
          <a href="#">item2</a>
          <a href="#">item3</a>
          <a href="#">item4</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="heading10">
        <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse10" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse10">Heading10</button>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse10" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading10" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="#">item1</a>
          <a href="#">item2</a>
          <a href="#">item3</a>
          <a href="#">item4</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="heading11">
        <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse11" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse11">Heading11</button>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse11" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading11" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="#">item1</a>
          <a href="#">item2</a>
          <a href="#">item3</a>
          <a href="#">item4</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="heading12">
        <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse12" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse12">Heading12</button>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse12" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading12" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="#">item1</a>
          <a href="#">item2</a>
          <a href="#">item3</a>
          <a href="#">item4</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately this won't work for me, as I said in my question: "The reason it is in two columns and not just split up in two inline divs is because it is generated by PHP and the number of accordions and items within them will change."

Comment: @PaddyHallihan do you mean that the HTML code is generated from a PHP function?

Comment: Yeah, so say that the accordion headings are product categories and the items within it are products but only certain products are available in different countries so all the HTML is generated from my database via PHP/MySQL

Comment: Can we see how it is generated? Because I worked with this kind of functions too and I always used bootstrap with generated code

Comment: @alesssz gave a good example. In php how do you download data, you know how many records you have so no problem to add an additional div that covers 50% of the recores :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this, First add two div ro one dive and class="row" and add col-md-6 to all the cards like below.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class col-md-6>
      <div class="card ">
        <div class="card-header" id="heading1">
             <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">Heading1</button>
        </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading1" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
         <a href="#">item1</a>
         <a href="#">item2</a>
         <a href="#">item3</a>
         <a href="#">item4</a>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class col-md-6>
     <div class="card">
       <div class="card-header" id="heading2">
           <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">Heading2</button>
       </div>
       <div id="collapse2" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading2" data-parent="#accordion">
          <div class="card-body">
              <a href="#">item1</a>
              <a href="#">item2</a>
              <a href="#">item3</a>
              <a href="#">item4</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Repeat this code every each two buttons.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had thought of this but then if I expand an element on one side the corresponding one in the same row will have the same height even though it is not expanded just leaving a big gap on the page

Comment: Sorry I have edited again. I have added to each card for one div in col-md-6